# QGIS 2.18 drain too much resources

Tags: qgis

I have opened in QGIS a georeferenced raster, a Google Maps layer (from OpenLayers plugin), 1-2 vector layers, and if I save or toggle editing the vector files QGIS freeze, just only the QGIS, the rest applications of my PC work fine.

I saw here some similar questions without a clear answer, but, I have to refer it somewhere. Here is a picture of my system usage while I was trying to turn off the toggle edit.

> PC details: Debian 8, processor Intel i7, RAM 4GB

[image]

Comment: The dataset you're trying to edit - how big is it (size, number of features, number of vertices)? Are you reprojecting any layers on-the-fly while editing? You're running 2.16 on which operating system? Finally, has this behaviour happened in any other QGIS versions?

Comment: Please **edit the question** to specify the system configuration properties. It appears you have 4Gb of RAM, which is not sufficient to run Windows, much less a GIS package. Based on your description of the task, 8-16Gb would be a more appropriate RAM  allocation.

Comment: @Phil G & Vince 
It's Debian 8 with i7 and 4GB RAM. The RAM is stable, it's the CPU that struggles while firefox,music player,file manager works fine.The raster image was 130mb when I made the question here, but later I re-edit it to 40MB but it kept doing the same freeze. Yes it is on the fly. The vector are about 200 points and another line vector, that connects them.

Comment: In other versions of Qgis, when it was open and the same time VLC was open too, one of them, sometimes, was crashing. It's a crash but I don't think is relevant.